# Battery Cable Replacement 1987 Chrysler 5th Avenue

Tags: chrysler, 5th-avenue

The negative battery cable on my 1987 Chrysler 5th Avenue is two-wire and very old and brittle.  The 4 ga cable connects to alternator; smaller lead to frame of car.  Both are about 20 inches in length.  Aftermarket cables are 20 inch with  6 in pigtails, butt splice connector.
Prefer not to extend the pigtail the required 14 in to frame. Can the old cable be replaced with two separate cables--- a 20 in  ground strap from the negative battery terminal to the frame; and a 20 in 4ga negative from the negative battery terminal to alternator?
Thank you

Ann

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is electrically equivalent, which is all that matters.